# Is there a word for the study of how technology shapes society

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for the field of study of how technology affects societies?

For example: How cheap cars affects the design of cities.

Comment: There's something called STS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science,_technology_and_society), although that looks at effects both ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in a [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/343776/is-there-a-word-for-the-study-of-how-technology-shapes-society#comment794390_343776), the closest thing would be STS, or Science, Technology, and Society. There is no one focus of scientific study on how technology affects society alone, but how they affect and develop each other. Here's a link to the National Science Foundation's division on STS: http://www.nsf.gov/funding/pgm_summ.jsp?pims_id=5324

Comment: Hi AKate47, welcome to English Language & Usage. If you think you might use our site again (and I hope you do!), please make sure you take the [Tour]. :-)